# Jenkins project running infinitely when using two repositories in source code management

Tags: git, docker, jenkins, docker-compose, continuous-integration

I want to build a docker image of a NodeJS api and push it to ECR. And also update the docker-compose file which is in other repo with the latest docker image for that service. I am using git commit hash for the tags of docker images being built. My Jenkins Project looks like[image]

Checking out two repos. customer-support-service contains the node rest api code and dockerfile.
docker-compose repo contains docker-compose.yml in which I will be updating the image url after new image is built.
My Build commands[image]
and after this, I am using Git Published in Post build section of the Jenkins project to update the docker-compose.yml file.
[image]
The issue is -  it becomes a loop and a new build starts after each build. and when I checked the console output I got this[image]
This line "scheduling another build to catch up with ..." is creating the loop. Not sure why this is happening but I just want this to start when there is a push on customer-support-service.git repo.
Console Output of the build -

`

```
Started by an SCM change
Running as SYSTEM
[lockable-resources] acquired lock on [docker-compose]
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/micro-services/docker-refiller-service
using credential 3cf7b600-83ed-4e96-9679-6cd9c811ece1
using credential 3cf7b600-83ed-4e96-9679-6cd9c811ece1
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from 2 remote Git repositories
 > git config remote.docker.url https://github.com/<ORG>/docker-compose # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/<ORG>/docker-compose
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > git fetch --tags --progress -- https://github.com/<ORG>/docker-compose +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/docker/* # timeout=10
 > git config remote.service.url https://github.com/<ORG>/kiosk-refill-service-beta.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/<ORG>/kiosk-refill-service-beta.git
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > git fetch --tags --progress -- https://github.com/<ORG>/kiosk-refill-service-beta.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/service/* # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse service/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/docker/service/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/service/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/service/service/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Multiple candidate revisions
Scheduling another build to catch up with micro-services » docker-refiller-service
Checking out Revision b95ad79d0f00850a2c002bf67fed1e099974ad2b (service/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f b95ad79d0f00850a2c002bf67fed1e099974ad2b # timeout=10
 > git branch -a -v --no-abbrev # timeout=10
 > git branch -D service/master # timeout=10
 > git checkout -b service/master b95ad79d0f00850a2c002bf67fed1e099974ad2b # timeout=10
Commit message: "Added File for testing"
 > git rev-list --no-walk b95ad79d0f00850a2c002bf67fed1e099974ad2b # timeout=10
provisioning config files...

[docker-refiller-service] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins1396736790531141219.sh
+ docker image rm kiosk-refiller-service:latest -f
Error: No such image: kiosk-refiller-service:latest
+ docker build --no-cache -t kiosk-refiller-service:latest . --build-arg arg=testing
Sending build context to Docker daemon   1.67MB

Step 1/10 : FROM node:9-slim
 ---> e20bb4abe4ee
Step 2/10 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Running in b6c8b1c01bb9
Removing intermediate container b6c8b1c01bb9
 ---> d567293c3246
Step 3/10 : COPY package.json /app
 ---> c0f80438537e
Step 4/10 : RUN npm install
 ...
Removing intermediate container 94b6f44d417a
 ---> 3c0944cc2725
Step 5/10 : COPY . /app
 ---> a5ae03447f7b
Step 6/10 : EXPOSE 3001
 ---> Running in 4b8813c1bd16
Removing intermediate container 4b8813c1bd16
 ---> d0230a119243
Step 7/10 : ARG arg
 ---> Running in b6b6d422c7bb
Removing intermediate container b6b6d422c7bb
 ---> 91e365c81ed6
Step 8/10 : RUN  echo $arg
 ---> Running in ed84f79a9483
testing
Removing intermediate container ed84f79a9483
 ---> a655eb036e1b
Step 9/10 : RUN if [ "$arg" = "testing" ] ; then npm test ; else  echo Not Testing $arg ; fi
 ---> Running in 798d774b99e2
Removing intermediate container 798d774b99e2
 ---> 333e5ac2cb93
Step 10/10 : CMD ["npm","start"]
 ---> Running in ff0ac4899989
Removing intermediate container ff0ac4899989
 ---> acc84b8ef96a
Successfully built acc84b8ef96a
Successfully tagged kiosk-refiller-service:latest
+ git rev-parse HEAD
+ docker tag kiosk-refiller-service:latest ECR-REPO-LINK/kiosk-refiller-service:b95ad79d0f00850a2c002bf67fed1e099974ad2b
+ git rev-parse HEAD
+ docker push ECR-REPO-LINK/kiosk-refiller-service:b95ad79d0f00850a2c002bf67fed1e099974ad2b
The push refers to repository [ECR-REPO-LINK/kiosk-refiller-service]
...
08588f4f94c4: Pushed
b95ad79d0f00850a2c002bf67fed1e099974ad2b: digest: sha256:e80f44c9c70368fc1db1469f84d13a41c38fe4e321a9d341771b8bc8892b54b0 size: 2416
+ docker image rm kiosk-refiller-service:latest -f
Untagged: kiosk-refiller-service:latest
+ git rev-parse HEAD
+ docker image rm ECR-REPO-LINK/kiosk-refiller-service:b95ad79d0f00850a2c002bf67fed1e099974ad2b -f
+ git rev-parse HEAD
+ export REFILLER_SERVICE_IMAGE_URL=ECR-REPO-LINK/kiosk-refiller-service:b95ad79d0f00850a2c002bf67fed1e099974ad2b
+ echo ECR-REPO-LINK/kiosk-refiller-service:b95ad79d0f00850a2c002bf67fed1e099974ad2b
ECR-REPO-LINK/kiosk-refiller-service:b95ad79d0f00850a2c002bf67fed1e099974ad2b
+ git checkout docker/Integration
Note: checking out 'docker/Integration'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b <new-branch-name>

HEAD is now at 1c75d32 Testing
+ sed -i s|ECR-REPO-LINK/kiosk-refiller-service:[0-9a-f]\{5,40\}|ECR-REPO-LINK/kiosk-refiller-service:b95ad79d0f00850a2c002bf67fed1e099974ad2b|g docker-compose.yml
+ cat docker-compose.yml
...
+ git status
HEAD detached at docker/Integration
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    .env
    login
    src/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
+ git diff --quiet
+ git diff --staged --quiet
using credential 3cf7b600-83ed-4e96-9679-6cd9c811ece1
using credential 3cf7b600-83ed-4e96-9679-6cd9c811ece1
Pushing HEAD to branch Integration at repo docker
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > git push https://github.com/Wendor-in/docker-compose HEAD:Integration -f # timeout=10
[lockable-resources] released lock on [docker-compose]
Finished: SUCCESS
```

`

Comment: Have you added "SCM Polling" option in "Build Triggers" ? Can you post entire job configuration?

Comment: Yes. I am using `GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling` option in Build Triggers section

Comment: I suppose that is the problem. You are polling 2 repos and at the end of the build, you are pushing to one of the repo, which in turn is triggering a new build and goes into the loop. This what I can make it from the details you have posted. Can you post more details on SCM Polling configuration?

Comment: I added the console output of whole build process. Take a look

Comment: There seems to be some issue in workspace which is creating problem when checking out from git remote repo and hence you are getting "Multiple candidate revisions". 

I found a Jenkins Issue posted here : https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-54102?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel

Do check if its exactly same as yours.